# GitHub Actions step summary reversed

Tags: powershell, github, github-actions

I just started adding GitHub Actions workflows to my Rust project, and wanted to have a basic custom step summary to show whether the steps had succeeded or failed. I read up on it and saw that I could add to the `$env:GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` variable to do this (it runs in PowerShell).

I thought that when things were added to this they would be appended to the end of the summary, which is what appears to happen in the examples I've seen. However, mine adds the new strings to the top instead. How can I append the text at each step?

My Action:

```yaml
jobs:
    build:
        name: Build, Test and Release
        runs-on: windows-latest
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v4
            - name: Prepare breakdown
              run: Add-Content -Path $env:GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY -Value "### Breakdown"
            - name: Build
              run: |
                  cargo build --release --verbose

                  if ($?) {
                      Add-Content -Path $env:GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY -Value "-  Build successful"
                  } else {
                      Add-Content -Path $env:GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY -Value "-  Build failed"
                  }
            - name: Run tests
              run: |
                  cargo test --verbose

                  if ($?) {
                      Add-Content -Path $env:GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY -Value "-  Tests passed"
                  } else {
                      Add-Content -Path $env:GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY -Value "-  Tests failed"
                  }
            - name: Extract version
              id: extract-version
              run: |
                  (Get-Content -Path Cargo.toml -Raw) -match 'version = "(.*?)"'
                  echo "VERSION=$matches[1]" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
            - name: Create release
              env:
                  GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
              run: |
                  gh release create "v${{ steps.extract-version.outputs.VERSION }}" "target/release/windough.exe" --generate-notes

                  if ($?) {
                      Add-Content -Path $env:GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY -Value "-  Release successful"
                  } else {
                      Add-Content -Path $env:GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY -Value "-  Release failed"
                  }
```

Result:

[image: Resulting Markdown]

Comment: What's the output if you use `Out-File` as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions?tool=powershell#adding-a-job-summary) instead of `Add-Content`?

Comment: Also, verify what happens if you you comment (skip) the last step i.e. `Create release`.

Comment: Tried to reproduce your scenario and the sequencing indeed is broken. Opened an issue for this, see https://github.com/github/docs/issues/31820.

Comment: Apart from the sequencing issue (which apparently is a bug), the last summary update in your workflow doesn't look right given that "**`GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` is unique for each step in a job.**" and "**After a step has completed, job summaries are uploaded and subsequent steps cannot modify previously uploaded Markdown content.**".

Comment: @Azeem Thanks for looking into this and opening an issue. You are right, the last summary update is a hangover from me trying to work out if I was updating the summary wrong, which I thought I had reverted.

Comment: **Update**: The bug has been fixed. It was due a change which has been reverted. I have verified and now the summary is working fine. Here's a sample run: https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/8084927171